# replace column entries by their column names

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, data.table

I want to replace a value (i.e. "x") in a data.table OR data.frame by its column name.

Example:

```
# sample data
Substance <- LETTERS[1:10]
Jan10 <- c("x","x",NA,NA,NA,"x","x","x","x",NA)
Apr10 <- c("x",NA,"x",NA,"x","x","x","x",NA,"x")
Jul10 <- c(NA,NA,NA,"x","x","x","x",NA,"x","x")
Oct10 <- c("x","x","x","x",NA,"x",NA,"x",NA,"x")

dt <- as.data.table(cbind(Substance, Jan10, Apr10, Jul10, Oct10))

# manually changing one column
dt[Jan10=="x", Jan10 := "Jan10"]
```

Aim: All the columns should look like the changed Jan10 column. How can I replace the "x" values in each column by the corresponding column name? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you have a `data.frame` and the columns are not factors, you could do `indx <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE) ; df[indx] <- names(df)[indx[, "col"]]`

Comment: Indeed I have factors. It works. Like below, the idea was to replace the "x", not the NAs.

Comment: So change `is.na(df)` to `df == "x"` and it is better to not use factors (or `cbind` ) if you are planning to change the values in the future. I read your data as follows `df <- data.frame(Substance, Jan10, Apr10, Jul10, Oct10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Sry, wanted to write characters instead of factors. Works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the columns, use `set` to replace the NA values with column names

```
for(j in 2:ncol(dt)){
    set(dt, i=which(dt[[j]]=="x"), j=j, value = names(dt)[j])
 }

dt
#    Substance Jan10 Apr10 Jul10 Oct10
# 1:         A Jan10 Apr10    NA Oct10
# 2:         B Jan10    NA    NA Oct10
# 3:         C    NA Apr10    NA Oct10
# 4:         D    NA    NA Jul10 Oct10
# 5:         E    NA Apr10 Jul10    NA
# 6:         F Jan10 Apr10 Jul10 Oct10
# 7:         G Jan10 Apr10 Jul10    NA
# 8:         H Jan10 Apr10    NA Oct10
# 9:         I Jan10    NA Jul10    NA
#10:         J    NA Apr10 Jul10 Oct10
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It works. However the idea was to change the "x" entries and not the NAs. I changed it accordingly!